# Imageview jump to start position

Tags: android, layout, imageview, margin

i have an imageview
and i move it in timer with:

```
  ImageView kembali = (ImageView) findViewById(idmusuh);                                                        
  kembali.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
  kembali.setLayoutParams(params);
```

so the imagview is move down 5px every timer tick
now if i click the button i want to put the imageview back to start position ..what is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
kembali.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            kembali.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

Given that you have moved the ImageView by increasing the margin...